# I use window.scrollBy() for smooth scroll but it doesn't work for Safari

Tags: javascript, scroll

I use `window.scrollBy()` for smooth scroll but it doesn't work for Safari. What is the best way to fix it?

```
function scroll(id: number) {
  for (let k = 0; k < sectionsForScroll.length; k++) {
    if (sectionsForScroll[k].dataset.navId == id) {
      const bigginer = sectionsForScroll[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
      console.log(bigginer + 'px  how far we from the start ');

      const distanceToGo = sectionsForScroll[k].getBoundingClientRect().top;
      console.log(sectionsForScroll[k].offsetTop);

      const distanceToScroll = bigginer - distanceToGo;
      console.log(distanceToGo + ' where we have to go ');
      console.log(distanceToScroll + ' what the distanse we need to scroll ');

      window.scrollBy({left:0, top:distanceToGo, behavior:"smooth"});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use element.scrollTop(). kindly refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop